# Drupal programmatic location_cck creation

Tags: drupal, location, cck

When using the followin code to define a cck location:

```
$location   =   array(
                    'latitude'      =>  "0.000000",
                    'longitude'     =>  "0.000000",
                    'street'        =>  "street is set",
                    'city'          =>  "city is set",
                    'postal_code'   =>  "post code set"
                );
                $newLocationID  =   location_save( $location );
```

All the information is created with the exception of the longitude and the latitude.

Can anyone tell me why and how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it.

As the best documentation is a source code, I had a look into the `location_save` function and found out that location module tries to get the latitude and longitude by geocoding, using function `_location_geo_logic`.

This is default setting and when you have a look into the  `_location_geo_logic` function you will notice, that this geocoding overwrites latitude and longitude keys in input array. However, this geocoding is only being done if the `$inhibit_geocode` variable is set to `FALSE`, so the only thing you have to do is add this key to the `$location array`:

```
$location['inhibit_geocode'] = TRUE;
```

For me it worked great, I hope so will for you.